# Is there anyway to capture lock screen with ffmpeg or electron getUserMedia

Tags: ffmpeg, electron, getusermedia, screen-capture

I'm trying to create a remote desktop app.

Everything is working great except I can't find a way to capture the windows lock screen to allow login from remote.

I'm using electron and getUserMedia which will show the lock screen on macOS but just hangs with a still image on Windows until the screen is unlocked.

Is there any way to capture the lock screen on windows using the built in getUserMedia or ffmpeg?
If not do you have any other suggestions of ways to capture? I don't need high framerate on the lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

I facet the same problem...
Maybe it's necessary to run electron app using System privileges.
do you have resolved in some way?